# typedef function keyword in lua

Tags: lua

For syntactic reasons I'd like to write functions LUA like:

```
on update()
    --do something
end
```

rather than the regular:

```
function update()
    --do something
end
```

Is it possible to (in effect) typedef or alias the 'function' keyword as 'on'?

Comment: You can change the source code of Lua to accept "on" as an alias for "function". It's pretty easy. You can also preprocess your Lua code with [ltokenp](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/index.html#ltokenp).

Comment: How would I safely do that while preserving the 'function' keyword?

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't possible, except if you process the Lua input to replace `on` with `function` before loading the program.

I suggest to consider alternatives, like

```
on.update = function ()
    -- do something
end

-- on can simply be an alternative name
-- for the global environment
on = _G
```

or define the program as a string

```
-- Update functions is defined as a string, loaded later.
on.update = [[
    -- do something
]]
```

For the latter to work, you'd have to set the `__newindex` metamethod to create a new function from the string by `load`ing the string and setting the resulting function as the field value.

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines at the end of [luaX_init](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/llex.c.html#luaX_init) in llex.c and rebuild Lua:

```
  {
    TString *ts = luaS_new(L, "on");
    luaC_fix(L, obj2gco(ts));  /* reserved words are never collected */
    ts->extra = cast_byte(TK_FUNCTION+1-FIRST_RESERVED);  /* reserved word */
  }
```